# Working with all models in workspace

Tags: eclipse-emf

Let's say I have Person EMF Model. I create 2 instances of this model bob.person and mike.person. Is there way to create a collection of all models in my workspace that are Person and query them using OCL or EMF Query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, definitely.

First, to create a collection of all models of some type in workspace use Eclipse Resources API.

```
IResourceVisitor
```

will come handy, searching for files with specific extensions, and putting them into collection. They can be loaded into a resource set with:

```
ResourceSet personSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
for (IResource res : foundIResources) {
  personSet.getResource(URI.createFileUTI(res.getFullPath(), true);
}
```

Next, you should execute a Query against a result set. You can either collect all the root elements of a resource set with:

```
Set<EObject> roots = new HashSet<EObject>;
for (Resource res : personSet.getResources()) {
  roots.addAll(res.getContent());
}
```

or create a

```
IEObjectSource
```

with similar functionality, to use with FROM EMF Model Query statement.